# How can show 0 in a group of sum?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a crosstab but I need a kind of query that repeat each policy_business_unit group by cia_ensures

My tables:

```
|policies|
  |id|  |client|  |policy_business_unit_id|  |cia_ensure_id|   |state|       
   1      MATT                  1                   1             0
   2      STEVE                 1                   2             1
   3      BILL                  1                   3             2
   4      LARRY                 1                   4             0

|policy_business_units|
   |id|   |name|  |comercial_area_id|
     1     LIFE         1 

|comercial_areas|
   |id|   |name|
    1      BANK

|cia_ensures|
   |id|   |name|
    1      SPRINT
    2      APPLE
    3      PEPSI
    4      ORANGE
    5      BT
```

Here is the information:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37690/2
```

I'm trying to show the calculations using all cia_ensures:

```
SELECT ce.name AS CIAS, pb.name AS UNIT,
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ACTIVES, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INACTIVES,
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS OTHERS
From policies p 
  INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
  INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
  INNER JOIN cia_ensures ce ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
WHERE policy_business_unit_id IN (1) 
GROUP BY cia_ensure_id
```

I'm getting this result:

```
UNIT             CIAS        COMERCIAL_AREAS    STATE_0   STATE_1   STATUS_2
 LIFE            SPRINT       BANK                  1       0           0
 LIFE            APPLE        BANK                  0       1           0
 LIFE            PEPSI        BANK                  0       0           1
 LIFE            ORANGE       BANK                  1       0           0
```

Here is my problem:
I want to show all cia_ensure_id and if this doesn't have relationship show 0

How can I do to have this result?

```
UNIT             CIAS        COMERCIAL_AREAS    STATE_0   STATE_1   STATUS_2
 LIFE            SPRINT       BANK                  1       0           0
 LIFE            APPLE        BANK                  0       1           0
 LIFE            PEPSI        BANK                  0       0           1
 LIFE            ORANGE       BANK                  1       0           0
 LIFE            BT           BANK                  0       0           0
```

I tried

```
SELECT ce.name AS CIAS, pb.name AS UNIT,
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ACTIVES, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INACTIVES,
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS OTHERS
From policies p 
  INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
  INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
  INNER JOIN cia_ensures ce ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
WHERE policy_business_unit_id IN (1) AND cia_ensured_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY cia_ensure_id
```

All kind of help will be accepted.

Please I will appreciate all kind of help.

Thanks.

Comment: Change the join to an outer join on cia_ensures.  INNER joins must have records in EVERY table or they get excluded.  Outer joins (left, right or full) will display all records in left, or right or both tables. unless filtered out in where clauses.

Comment: read up on LEFT JOIN, I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok i changed "outer join cia_ensures ce ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id" but got error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ce.name AS CIAS, pb.name AS UNIT,
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ACTIVES, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INACTIVES,
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS OTHERS
From policies p 
  INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
  INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
  RIGHT JOIN cia_ensures ce ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
WHERE (policy_business_unit_id IN (1) or policy_business_unit_id is null)
GROUP BY cia_ensure_id
```

changed inner to right, could be left if it was before the other tables, right since it's the last table.  basically you want all records from CIA and only those that match in the other tables.

note you also had to look for null values on policy_business_Unit otherwise the (1) would exclude the row added by the right join.

OR move the criteria to the join so it only applies the the rows before the join

```
SELECT ce.name AS CIAS, pb.name AS UNIT,
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ACTIVES, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INACTIVES,
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS OTHERS
From policies p 
  INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb 
    ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id 
    and policy_business_unit_id IN (1)
  INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
  RIGHT JOIN cia_ensures ce ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
GROUP BY cia_ensure_id
```

Assuming all NULL PB.names can read 'LIFE' then change the first select line to read...  but this is a bad assumption for me to make.  So unless there's a rule governing this, null should be the valid response based on design.

```
SELECT ce.name AS CIAS, coalesce(pb.name,'LIFE') AS UNIT,
```

Comment: burned by mySQL's implementation of Group by change group by to `ce.name` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/657b6/8/0

Comment: the problem with that is you are referencing policies cia_ensure_ID a policy may not exist for the cia_ensure you're wanting to display so you have to change to look at the cia_ensures ID instead of the one on policies as such (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/657b6/22/0) assuming you still want all cia_ensures but only those in your list and you need to continue to use the null notation on the policy_business_business_Id or you'll filter out cia_ensures as well.

Comment: You really need to look at your where clause anytime you have an outer join and where clause has to either move to the Join itself, or evaluate the criteria to or is null.  Otherwise the outer join is invalidated.  In this case http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/657b6/24/0  you'll note all I did was add `(pb.id = 1 or Pb.id is null)` the or pb.id is null.